# IdHttp : how to deal with json request and response

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe, idhttp

I have encountered a few sites that uses `JSON` for request and response
I come across two types :
**1-** `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as request and return a response `application/json` content type
**2-** `application/json` content type for both request and response
in `type 1` i tried changing the the response content type using
`mIdHttp.Response.ContentType := 'application/json';`
but using http analyzer i can see that it doesn't change and its still `text/html`
now i do not know if the problem is with the fact that i can't change content type or not but i do not know how to deal with `json` !
a few question regarding `json` :
**1-** do i have to encode json data when posting ? how ?
**2-** how can i parse the json response code ? how to get it ? does it need some kind of encode or special convertion ?
**3-** what kind of idhttp setting for json changes with each site and needs configuring ?

I understand my questions sound a bit general, but all the other questions are very specific and don't explain the basics when dealing with `'application/json'` content type.

**Edit 1 :**
thanks to **Remy Lebeau**  answer i was able to successfully work with `type 1`
but i still have trouble sending `JSON` request, can someone please share an working example, this is one of the sites posting information please use this for your example :
[image]

**One important note :**  this particular site's post and request content are exactly like each other ! and it baffles me because at the site, i specify an `start date` and an `end date` then click on a `folder like icon` and this `post` is sent (the one you can see above), and the `result` should be `links` (and it is) **but** instead of appearing only in `request content` they also appear in `post` !  (also i'm trying to get the links but at the `post` the links, the thing i want, are also being sent, how can i post something i don't have !!?)

**just for more clarity** here is the place i fill the date and the icon i mentioned :
[image]

Comment: There is no universal solution. Each implementation can be different. You can control if you want Indy to encode parameters using `hoForceEncodeParams` in `FHTTP.HTTPOptions` (if you send JSON data in your request, many sites don't allow encoded request). You should NOT set `Response.ContentType`. That is what server returns. You have to set `Request.ContentType` (what you send) and `Request.Accept` (what you expect from server)

Comment: @smooty86 the `hoForceEncodeParams` flag only applies when posting a `TStrings` in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. It does not apply in this situation, as you cannot post JSON using a `TStrings`, you have to use a `TStream` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you bet I can send JSON in TStrings :) Though I understand it can be less effective.

Comment: You send JSON like any other Post request. Provide your code how you send it. How exactly looks the "Raw stream" with post? It is not not clear in the parsed mode.

Comment: @smooty86 if you post a `TStrings` with `TIdHTTP`, it is expected to be a list of "name=value" pairs, and will be encoded accordingly. I have yet to encounter a website that accepts something like "fieldname=json" as input. Not that it can't, but it is extremely rare. Same goes with XML, too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If hoForceEncodeParams is off and JSON is one line TStrings, then it will work correctly. No encoding involved.

Comment: @smooty86: It might "work", but that is not how `TIdHTTP` is intended to be used. Why would you use a `TStrings` to send a complete JSON document as a single string? I would suggest using `TStringStream` for that, if not `TMemoryStream` or even `TIdMemoryBufferStream`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot specify the format of the response, unless the requested resource offers an explicit input parameter or dedicated URL for that exact purpose (ie, to request a response be sent as html, xml, json, etc).  Setting the `TIdHTTP.Response.ContentType` property is useless. It will be overwritten by the actual `Content-Type` header of the response.

To *send* JSON in a request, you must post it as a `TStream`, like `TMemoryStream` or `TStringStream`, and set the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` as needed, eg:

```
var
  ReqJson: TStringStream;
begin
  ReqJson := TStringStream.Create('json content here', TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    IdHTTP1.Post(URL, ReqJson);
  finally
    ReqJson.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To *receive* JSON, `TIdHTTP` can either

1. return it as a `String` (decoded using a server-reported charset):

   ```
   var
     ReqJson: TStringStream;
     RespJson: String;
   begin
     ReqJson := TStringStream.Create('json content here', TEncoding.UTF8);
     try
       IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
       RespJson := IdHTTP1.Post(URL, ReqJson);
     finally
       ReqJson.Free;
     end;
     // use RespJson as needed...
   end;
   ```
2. write the raw bytes to an output `TStream` of your choosing:

   ```
   var
     ReqJson: TStringStream;
     RespJson: TMemoryStream;
   begin
     RespJson := TMemoryStream.Create;
     try
       ReqJson := TStringStream.Create('json content here', TEncoding.UTF8);
       try
         IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
         RespJson := IdHTTP1.Post(URL, ReqJson, RespJson);
       finally
         ReqJson.Free;
       end;
       RespJson.Position := 0;
       // use RespJson as needed...
     finally
       RespJson.Free;
     end;
   end;
   ```

The HTTP response code is available in the `TIdHTTP.Response.ResponseCode` (and `TIdHTTP.ResponseCode`) property.

Comment: what you said helped me with the `first type`, but i still have problem with `second type`, i edited my question can you please read it and answer me accordingly, Thank you very much!

Comment: @AliAhmadi what exactly are you having trouble with? Your edit does not make it any clearer. What is so hard about putting the JSON content as-is into a `TStream` descendant and then posting it? Do you know how to produce JSON in the first place?

Comment: what do you mean by `produce JSON`, maybe that is my problem ? (as i said, i do not know the basics about `JSON`, a simple example would be more than enough, thx)

Comment: @AliAhmadi: I have added examples to my answer.  But how do you expect to send the JSON if you don't know how to produce it in the first place? See [Embarcadero's JSON documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Json).